# Some confusions about pointers to data-member in C++

Tags: c++

```
class Foo {
    public:
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    cout << &Foo::a << endl;//output 1
    cout << &Foo::b << endl;//also output 1
}
```

As we know pointers to member data should point out the relative offset from the start address of the object, but as the example shows, both pointers to Foo::a and Foo::b get a `1`. Would anyone can explain what happened here?

Comment: "As we know pointers to member data should point out the relative offset from the start address of the object" - what part of the C++ standard do you believe gives you that guarantee?

Comment: Did you mean `Foo` in `&Foo::a`?

Comment: Ummm, optimized away?

Comment: The value 1 is because `&Foo::a` is being converted to a bool.  If you `cout << std::boolalpha` you'll see true printed (include iomanip).

Comment: I am not familiar with using a pointer to data member's value, itself, without an instance of the class. If I use correct syntax and foo, I get the values 1 and 2 (which are the values, not the addresses). Do you want to know a portable way to take the binary offset of a data member, relative to the class pointer?

Comment: @Eljay Actually I do not really look up the language standard. Recently I read the book *Inside the C++ Object Model*, and I come up with an example `&origin + (Point3d::_y - 1) `whill get the address of origin._y, so I tried on my gcc4.9, then I become confused just like this.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, a pointer-to-member is NOT required to be implemented as an offset from the "start address of the object" (a concept which is not part of the language standard). And indeed, certain types of member pointers couldn't be implemented like that.

What you're seeing, instead, is simply `basic_ostream::operator<<(bool)`. Pointers to members can't be implicitly converted to many other types, but they can be converted to `bool`. The `1` you're seeing is simply an indication that you've passed a non-null member pointer.

Comment: Thank you! No longer confused about this. Now I have another question. I have read the book like *Inside the C++ Object Model*, or the [blog](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm), and they all say pointer to class member is not regular pointer but the offset, is it the old style of C++ implementation or it never exsits?

Comment: @J.zhou The C++ _standard_ doesn't guarantee that, but most C++ _implementation_ use this, as it is the simplest way.

Answer (score 4):

Although the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138577) provided by Sneftel is correct, this is one way to view the "actual" (internal) value of the pointer-to-members:

```
#include <iostream>

struct x {
    int a, b;
};

int main() {
    int x::* pa = &x::a;
    int x::* pb = &x::b;

    std::cout << pa << ' ' << pb << '\n';
    std::cout << *(int*)&pa << ' ' << *(int*)&pb << '\n';
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzdCsIwDIXv8xQBYT9FX6CtPok3bTak4LriWhjInr2mY4ypCYRz8uWEQrg8iHI@OU/P1PWo3TjFV2@GGwCLRBFnfANyOR/RnNEqWBRAcYNxvmkPeJZSYDB4xYqlUT/AboBfrGSKnZQ0pohalxjPmrsYu5q7r9X/pWj4pWirr8S@PCSXnD8)

This may have different values or cause undefined behavior, depends on the implementation. Also there is no guarantee that `sizeof int == sizeof pa`.

Comment: This specific code will work on all modern compilers I'm familiar with, but note that it's relying on those compilers' willingness to ignore the strict aliasing rule, as well as on how they implement pointers to non-virtual data members with no virtual inheritance. A good way to look under the hood, but of course not to be used in real code.

Comment: Not only is there no guarantee that `sizeof int == sizeof pa`  in practise it is not true in a strictly conforming C++ compiler (although it may be in MSVC in its default mode).  In general a pointer-to-member has got to be able to point to an int in a virtual base class of 'x', and then has to be convertible to a pointer-to-member of `class derived: public bar, public x`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the good way to get the relationship between pointer to member data and offset.

Answer (score 4):

Most compilers support use of the `offsetof` macro defined in `<cstddef>`. Just beware the pitfalls, quoting [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) :

> If type is not a standard layout type, the behavior is undefined
>   (until C++17)use of the offsetof macro is conditionally-supported
>   (since C++17).
>
> If member is a static member or a member function, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

class Foo {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << offsetof(Foo, a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << offsetof(Foo, b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you gor answering the question, I'm confused about why the two different pointers to member data output the same value '1'. Now I know how to get the offset! Thanks angain.